# How do I insert my values from a dynamic table to phpmyadmin?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

Okay, So the table for my added row works well but I can't add the values into my database. Idk if this is the connection problem or the way I write my code. And i'm new to AJAX and Json as well. I don't really get it. This is my codes for my submit page.

[1]submit.php

```
<?php
$num =  $_POST['rowcount'];
 for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){




          $Medication[] = $_POST["Medication"];
          $Forms[] = $_POST["Forms"];
          $Dosage[] = $_POST["Dosage"];
          $Frequency[] = $_POST["Frequency"];
}
?>
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $dbname, $password, $dbname) or die("Could not connect to database");    

    $stmt = $mysqli-> prepare(
    "INSERT INTO Medicine
    (Medication,Forms,Dosage,Frequency)
    VALUES
    (?,?,?,?);
    ");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$Medication,$Forms,$Dosage,$Frequency);

   $result =$stmt->execute();   

        if (!$result) {
        echo "die ";
        }
        else{ 


$arr = json_decode($_POST['json']);




for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)


{



echo "Row ".$i."\n";
 echo "Medication > ".$arr[$i]->Medication.", Forms > ".$arr[$i]->Forms.", Dosage > ".$arr[$i]->Dosage.", Frequency > ".$arr[$i]->Frequency."\n";



  }}
 $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Your code is missing a lot of important pieces. your first for loop has no {} for the actual code block. also too in your second if block your else statement is missing it's {} in the else block.